# Importing vector layers where geometry is WKT in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry, import, well-known-text

I am trying to import the layers in QGIS to PostGIS. However, I want the geometry imported to be WKT and not WKB. How can I do that?

Comment: After import, the PostGIS `GEOMETRY` type internal representation is neither WKB nor WKT, but an own, more compressable byte encoding. Ideally you only tranform to other formats on the fly when needed.

Comment: You can save the WKT geometry as a normal text attribute and discard the geometry column. In that case the PostGIS table will be a pure  attribute table without any spatial capabilities. Is that your aim? That is an uncommon scenario and it is not supported in QGIS directly but it can be done.

Comment: I think in this case I will stick to transforming the column when needed.  The thing is I am trying to use the geometry to write geosparql queries where only wkt is supported. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but storing the shape as GEOMETRY is preferred and that can be used directly in the QGIS.

In another case, you can use GENERATED COLUMNS to create a GEOMETRY column from the WKT column.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD COLUMN geometry_column GEOMETRY AS (
    ST_GeomFromText(wkt_column)
) STORED;
```

You can also create MATERIALIZED VIEWS if you are testing something out or just looking at the data and don't want to alter the original table.